# Using ip-camera in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, ip-camera, tensorflow.js

I'm using tensorflow.js (tfjs), especially posnet (pos estimation) and it gives very promising results.
The next step for me is now to use ip-cameras for the detection instead of the connected webcam.

Let say for example a stream like 
**http://192.168.1.76/cgi-bin/hi3510/snap.cgi?&-getstream&-chn=1**
or 
**rtsp://192.168.1.76:554/11**

I didn't find anything on the net to help me. 
So my question is: what should I change in the setupCamera() (see bellow) in order to get the ip-camera streams instead?

```
async function setupCamera() {
  if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
    throw new Error(
        'Browser API navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not available');
  }

  const video = document.getElementById('video');
  video.width = videoWidth;
  video.height = videoHeight;

  const mobile = isMobile();
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    'audio': false,
    'video': {
      facingMode: 'user',
      width: mobile ? undefined : videoWidth,
      height: mobile ? undefined : videoHeight,
    },
  });
  video.srcObject = stream;

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
      resolve(video);
    };
  });
}
```

I'm sorry for this newbie like question, thanks for your help.
senso

Comment: Have you tested it already and generated some kind of error?

Comment: Are you able to display the rtsp stream in the browser ?

Comment: yes the http stream works in the browser. I just want to change the code above to make it working with this stream. My camera also provide a rtp stream.

Comment: Hi oliver, I'm also looking into same. Please let me know how did you fixed. Thank you.